# Python django modify help file

Tags: python, django, command

I would like to modify -h command in django project. I created a project but when I use my own help command `python manage.py my_help` I get an error about not installed modules. And this is ok, because I would like to inform user which modules are needed to install before run a project. So, when I call `python manage.py my_help` or `python manage.py -h` I want to show info about additional modules which are needed and general info about project. Now I got only error messsages like (I'm using reportlab in project)

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4, letter
ImportError: No module named 'reportlab'
```

Is it possible to modify default -h option or do something with my own help command to show basic info instead of an error?

**EDIT:**

Where can I put argparse code to modify my -h option? I put it in manage.py and when I run `python manage.py -h` it shows, but when I run `python manage.py runserver`, I got `manage.py: error: unrecognized arguments: runserver`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify your import statements like this:

```
try:
    from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4, letter
except ImportError:
    print 'Missing dependency reportlab'
```

But this is rather unusual. The usual practice is to create a requirments.txt file which can be passed to pip as follows

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Which enables the user to easily satisfy all the requirements in one command. If you catch each `ImportError` and print out a message for each requirement, you are actually forcing the user to type pip install multiple times.

Comment: second for for requirements.txt, much easier way!

Comment: I have a question - where should I place argparser argument to modify -h option in django? I placed it in manage.py, but when I want to run a server I get manage.py: error: unrecognized arguments: runserver

Comment: I think you need to post that as a new question.

Comment: Ok, I created http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40887725/django-where-put-argparse-command-to-modify-h-option