# Django - where put argparse command to modify -h option?

Tags: django, command, argparse

I would like to modify my help option in project I created. 
I put argparse in manage.py file, like this

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description="Some desc",
    formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter
)
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Reporter.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError:
        # The above import may fail for some other reason. Ensure that the
        # issue is really that Django is missing to avoid masking other
        # exceptions on Python 2.
        try:
            import django
        except ImportError:
            raise ImportError(
                "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
                "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
                "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
            )
        raise
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

but when I run python manage.py -h it works correctly (help shows), but when I run `python manage.py runserver`, I got: `manage.py: error: unrecognized arguments: runserver`
How to solve this problem? I really don't know how to modify -h option.

Where should I put argparse code to get help in this django project? I know I can use own command, but it is important to me to get help after I make `python manage.py -h`

**EDIT:**

After help from comments, I created:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


def help_parser():
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("Some desc",
        formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args[0])


def main():
    import os
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Reporter.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError:
        # The above import may fail for some other reason. Ensure that the
        # issue is really that Django is missing to avoid masking other
        # exceptions on Python 2.
        try:
            import django
        except ImportError:
            raise ImportError(
                "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
                "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
                "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
            )
        raise
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    if sys.argv[1] == '-h':
        help_parser()
    else:
        main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably ought not to introduce argparse into the picture here. Argparse and Argh are pretty usefull if you are writing a [django CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32091771/267540) but not very helpful for adding a custom management command because the management api has most the requirements already built in albeit in a very different way.

For example, you can automatically get your command to show up when `./manage.py -h` is executed merely by placing the .py file in the right location. For example if you create a file as

```
myapp/management/commands/custom.py
```

executing manage.py -h will reveal

```
[myapp]
    custom
```

You can customize it further by over setting the help variable.

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Custom help message here'
```

Now ./manage.py custom -h will reveal (among other things)

```
Closes the specified poll for voting
```

Comment: I understand. But what if someone has not installed additional modules which I include in my app. Then when manage.py custom -h does not show help but list of errors. How can I show help even if errors appeared?

Comment: I am beginning to think that what you are really trying to create is a Django CLI app rather than a django web app

Comment: I know I have requirements.txt. but  the story of this app is more complicated. This is my studies app and teacher said that I should show help even if the list of errors appears. I know it is stupid but I want to be sure thst it is impossible. Well, the best way is to first install all modules from requirements and then call custom help command?

Comment: Believe me, I am so angry. Sorry for stupid question but I needed to confirm this. I'm going to tell him that only way to solve this and get help is to install all require modules. Thank you for your help

Comment: So copy manage.py in same directory, change name of orginal and put my code with help in new one? Than will be no problems with runserver etc.?

Comment: nopes, if the parameter is anything other than -h just execute the original manage.py

Comment: come to think of it, you can even actually make it work by moving what's under the `__main__` block to a separate function. So you have two functions in manage.py, the first one get's called when the argument is -h, the second one for everything else. Make sure that all the imports in manage.py are also moved to inside those functions rather than being at the top level.

Comment: Yeah I understand. I think I can modify only manage.py, add -h parameter recognize and just write a simple if statemant.

Comment: I updated my post with new code. This is something we have talked about?

Comment: yes, that ought to do it, I modded just one line in my new answer

Answer (score 1):

Adding a new answer based on discussions.

You can keep your teacher happy by moving what's under the `__main__` block to a separate function. So you have two functions in `manage.py`, the first one get's called when the argument is -h, the second one for everything else. Make sure that all the imports in manage.py are also moved to inside those functions rather than being at the top level.

Then

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    if len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1] == '-h':
        help_parser()
    else:
        main()
```

Where main() contains the standard django manage.py code. Notice that you don't really need argparse here because now help_parser() only displays the help message for your app and doesn't have anything else to do.

Comment: glad to have been of help, all the best with your project